# Grab data from bitfinex with Python

Tags: python

I'm using this :

```
import requests

url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

print (response.text)
```

The output is:

```
{"mid":"4432.95","bid":"4432.9","ask":"4433.0","last_price":"4432.9","low":"4276.9","high":"4482.0","volume":"32877.86104158","timestamp":"1506955900.864889"}
```

I would like to grab the last price, as a float, in order to use it for some calculations....

I cannot figure out how to do that...
Can you help me please ?
Thx

Comment: There is ultimate course in Python for the beginners from MIT, and it is absolutely free: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytpJdnlu9ug&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63WbdFxL8giv4yhgdMGaZNA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

data = response.json()
last_price = float(data.get('last_price'))
print(last_price)
```

Comment: Thank you !
I like your solution because it creates a variable that I can easily re-use.

Comment: Cool, im glad that it helps you. I you can mark it as the correct answer it would be really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Response is a JSON so `requests` will do the job of parsing it for you, if you call the `.json()` method on your response. You just need to do:

```
import requests

resp_json = requests.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd").json()
# resp_json is a native Python dict representing the JSON response content. But since all values are strings in the response, you need to convert them to a float manually.
print(float(resp_json["last_price"]))
```